# kafka-connect sink connector pk.mode for table with auto-increment

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm working on kafka-connect JDBC sink connector for a database table.

I'm having trouble configuring the pk.mode to the proper one that supports auto-increment. Originally I set the pk.mode to the default "none" and hope the database would automatically insert a new record with the primary key incremented by one. However I get error complaining that the primary key cannot be "null".

I tried almost all other modes and running out of ideas now. I wonder if the sink connector ever supports pk.mode to be "auto-increment"?

Comment: Please share your ddl of the table, and your connector config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized that I made a mistake in the schema I created for the sink connector.

I include the primary key field in the schema and this field was unset, so when it reached to the sink connector it will complain that the primary key cannot be null.

In order to rely on the auto-increment feature from the db, the schema for the sink connector MUST NOT include the primary key. So after I removed the primary key from the schema and set the `pk.mode` to `none`, everything works properly.