# Kafka Connect sink connector configured for both insert and update

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a MySQL database and I use the Confluent Kafka Connect JDBC Sink Connector to insert elements into the table (I am not able to make any changes to the database schemas... other systems rely upon it in its current state).  The primary key is set to auto-increment to prevent the possibility of two clients trying to claim the same ID at the same time, so I can't specify it for the insert.  The config below is representative of what I would use for insert:

```
{
    "name": "sink-connector-insert",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://server:3306/database?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false"
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://registry:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://registry:8081",
    "topics": "table",
    "connection.user": "user",
    "connection.password": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "ssl.mode": "prefer",
    "insert.mode": "insert",
}
```

Later I may want to update the same record, but at that point I know the key and so will include it in the update message.  And this one for the update:

```
{
    "name": "sink-connector-update",
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:mysql://server:3306/database?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false"
    "key.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://registry:8081",
    "value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "https://registry:8081",
    "topics": "table",
    "connection.user": "user",
    "connection.password": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "ssl.mode": "prefer",
    "insert.mode": "update",
    "pk.mode": "record_value",
    "pk.fields": "id"
}
```

The naming conventions Kafka Connect uses to tie the topic name to the table name lead to a conflict in the connector actually used... when I do an insert, the update (or upsert) connector will enter a failed state since it needs a key, which I don't have for the insert, and when I try to run an update operation with the key, the insert connector will enter a failed state because it will induce a key collision.

Is there a way I can configure some number of Kafka Connect JDBC Sink connectors and Kafka topics to distinguish between insert and update operations on the same table in a MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

> lead to a conflict in the connector actually used

The connector name isn't the problem for the table. It's that both create unique consumer groups, therefore are processing the exact same offsets, so there's no ordering guarantee that an "update" gets a record after any insert. And even if it did, it'd immediately send an update query for the exact same data.

One connector with `upsert` insert mode does what you need, regardless of the key requirements. Besides, you're using `record_value` mode, so it's already ignoring any Kafka record keys you may have.

---

Related post [kafka-connect sink connector pk.mode for table with auto-increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67829162/kafka-connect-sink-connector-pk-mode-for-table-with-auto-increment)

> removed the primary key from the schema and **set the `pk.mode` to `none`**, everything works properly.

Although, I'm not sure how that'll work out for update queries. You may need a different topic for that, but you can still use RegexRouter transform to manipulate the table name so it doesn't need to match the topic.

Comment: Thanks... thought I tried the upsert before and it got upset when I didn't specify the key... but I'll give it another try on Monday.

Comment: And I see in the link you sent, I just need to set pk.mode to none... will give that a try.  Thanks again.

Comment: Circling back on this... after following instructions on the question / answer you linked.   I removed the pk field in the schema and set "pk.mode" to none. and now I'm getting "Write to table '\"table\"' in UPSERT mode requires key field names to be known, check the primary key configuration".  Suggestions?